# Javascript while and do/while loops

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have this code who works properly with for loop, how to made while and do/while loop to work properly on same way when i click on button?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick = "fun()">Click
        </button>
        <p id = "dr">
        </p>
            <script>
                function fun() {
                    var str = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                            str = str + i + "<br/>";
                            document.getElementById("dr").innerHTML = str;
                        } 
                 }
            </script>
    </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Comment: That code, in fact, does not work even as a `for` loop.  The value `I` is never defined, and the curly braces don't match up.  As for making it a `while` loop, what have you tried?  Why do you even need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like HW, so I won't give you the entire code.

However, you have this code in your for loop

```
for (var i=0; I<11; i++)
}
```

In that, `I` is never defined, so you should probably change it to `i`.

For changing it to a `do{}..while()` loop, remember that every for loop of the form `for(a;b;c){d;}` can be expanded to the while loop

```
a;
while(b){
    d;
    c;
}
```

and therefore to the `do..while` loop of

```
a;
do{
    d;
    c;
}while(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

while:

```
function fun()
{
   var str ="";
   while( i < 11 )
   {
        str=str + i +"<br/>";
        document.getElementById("dr").innerHTML =srt;
        i++;
   }
}
```

do/while:

```
function fun()
{
   var str ="";
   do
   {
        str=str + i +"<br/>";
        document.getElementById("dr").innerHTML =srt;
        i++;
   }while( i < 11 );
}
```